How to Scale the Lower Part of a UV Sphere in Blender
I'm following a  YouTube video by Default Cube and can't figure out how to scale the lower part of a UV sphere as shown in the clip below.

The result I get is very different, and I can't figure out why. Can anyone here on the forum explain?

Here is a summary of the different steps as I understand
Object Mode:

Launch Blender and delete everything.
Add a UV Sphere with 100 segments and 100 rings.

Edit Mode:

Select the equatorial line of the sphere using edge loop selection.
Mark the seam.
Change Select Mode to faces.
Hover the mouse over the lower part of the UV sphere and press 'L' to select connected geometry.
Set the Transform Pivot Point to 3D cursor.
Press 'S' to scale.

... and the result can not be reproduced as shown in the video.

He doesn't say it, but the blue vertical line while shows he's scaling on Z axis, also the tool information in the top left of the viewport says "Scaling [some factor] on global Z".

Press SZ to scale on Z only.........
